# Android Default Calendar Application, Can I Use It's Day View Object I Can Use In My Application

Tags: android, android-layout, calendar

I have been looking around and what I have found is a google code project for calendar view but it's not what I'm looking for.

What I'd like is the ability to use the view that is the default day view of the default Calendar application. Does anyone know whether or not I can use it's day view in my app or if their is one that was developed and released that I can use?

Again I don't want a full month view or really even a week view. At the moment I just want a day view like so many of us use to quickly glance at what we've got going on for the day.

I'm also not interested at this time of fetching google calendar appointments or merging with them. This will be a separate list of appointments / tasks that from their own data source. I have all that done now I'm just trying to find a pretty way to display them (listview is a tad bit basic lol).

Comment: I guess that if you only need a day view, and if you dont want to conect this view to the google calendar, then why dont create your on "day view"? At the end, is just a bitmap with some lines and rectangles on it...

Comment: Just want to make sure I wouldn't be re-inventing the wheel!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone know whether or not I can use it's day view in my app or if their is one that was developed and released that I can use?

You can probably find the source code for it in the Android open source project, but it may not be designed for reuse.

Android 3.x has a `CalendarView` widget; once the source code for Android 3.x is released (hopefully later this year), it may be that you can back-port that to older Android versions.

The [iosched](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/) application from Google I|O 2011 has its own calendar view.

Comment: Hey, I know it has been a while since you answered this question @CommonsWare but I tried looking at the iosched code, and I can't find the part that creates the day view and puts the events in correct time slots. The help would be greatly appreciated as I am new at android development!

Comment: @Andy: Beats me -- I haven't really looked.

Comment: Now I know why this question never got an answer. Because it isn't much of an answer -_- Thanks anyways. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Most of the functionality that is hard to write is already in the java.util.Calendar class and subclasses. It should be fairly easy to write a thin UI wrapper around an instance of Calendar? You would only be re-inventing the user interface, not date logic :-)